# Activity restart before closing android

Tags: java, android

I'm creating an android application which have three activities first one is sign-in activity second is screen as splash screen which I want to display for three seconds finally third activity will start.
this is my code for three activities
sign-in activity :

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

    @BindView(R.id.textView)
    TextView textView;
    @BindView(R.id.imageView2)
    ImageView img;
    @BindView(R.id.txt_username)
    TextView txt_username;
    @BindView(R.id.editTextTextPersonName)
    EditText txt_user;
    @BindView(R.id.txt_password)
    TextView txt_password;
    @BindView(R.id.editTextTextPassword)
    EditText txt_pass;
    @BindView(R.id.button)
    Button btn;

    DBConnection connection;
    ArrayList<String> list;
    String[] arr;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        connection = new DBConnection(this);
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo);

        list = connection.Get_Users();
        arr = list.get(0).split("\n");
    }
    @OnClick(R.id.button)
    public void onViewClicked() {
        String username = txt_user.getText().toString();
        String password = txt_pass.getText().toString();
        if(username.equals(arr[0]) && password.equals(arr[1])) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this,Loading_Screen.class);
            intent.putExtra("name",username);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        } else {
            Functions.Make_Toast(getBaseContext(),"Incorrect username or password");
        }
    }
}
```

Loading_Screen activity:

```
public class Loadin_Screen extends AppCompatActivity {

    @BindView(R.id.img_load)
    GifImageView imgLoad;

    private final int SPLASH_SCREEN_TIME = 3000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_loading__screen);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        imgLoad.setImageResource(R.drawable.load);
        
        String username = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Loading_Screen.this,Account_List.class);
                intent.putExtra("name",username);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        },SPLASH_SCREEN_TIME);
    }
}
```

MainActivity:

```
public class Account_List extends AppCompatActivity {

    @BindView(R.id.txt)
    TextView txt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_account__list);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        String user = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
        txt.setText("Hello "+user);
    }
}
```

this code worked well for me but the problem faced me when I want to close application by pressing on back button from MainActivity restart MainActivity so I should press back button again to close application.
so, what can I do to close application by one click on back button ?

Answer (score 0):

You can clear all prvious activity from the back stack to make sure that the current activity (main activity) is the only activity in the back stack; so when hitting the back button, the main activity gets out of the back stack and shut down the app.

To do so, make sure that you clear the back stack whenever you open the main activity by attaching the `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` & `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` flags to your intent:

```
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Loading_Screen.this,Account_List.class);
            intent.putExtra("name",username);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    },SPLASH_SCREEN_TIME);
```